# Excel 2016. Apostrophes in excel formula

Tags: java, excel, excel-formula, apache-poi

I have an excel file with 2 pages.
The first page "**sheet_n1**" have formula with reference to another page `=MAX(sheet_n2!A1:sheet_n2!A3)`
The second page "**sheet_n2**" have a table with data.

After saving, I open my excel file as ZIP-archive. And in the XML-file of "**sheet_n1**" I have apostrophes in formula on second part of range `=MAX(sheet_n2!A1:'sheet_n2'!A3)`

This does not affect how the formula works in the excel. And I don't see these apostrophes in excel app.

But this affects opening a file using an Apache POI library in my Java application. I have apostrophes when I read a cell with formula

Can someone explain where these apostrophes come from ? And why only in the second part of the formula?

Comment: You must have them if there is a space in the sheet name. Maybe you have a space?

Comment: @Andreas, Yeah, I know about apostrophes for sheet names with space. But I don't have spaces. And I have similar parts with another sheet name in formula. But first part saving without apostrophes, and second part with apostrophes (I showed this in example). I don't know why

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`=MAX(17, 'sheet_n2'!A3)` is correct syntax. The sheet name is surrounded by inverted commas. That's the rule.

However, Microsoft, in its never ending effort to make things easier, determined that they can be left out if there is no space in the tab name. The consequence is that Excel will remove the commas if there is no space in the name even if you type them. But if you use Excel in other languages, including VBA, the commas will not be removed even though they may not be needed. Appache POI is likely aware of this and would know how to deal with the commas.

`=MAX(sheet_n2!A1:'sheet_n2'!A3)` is a special case because the second mention of the sheet isn't required. `=MAX(sheet_n2!A1:A3)` is adequate. So, Excel doesn't quite know what to do with the extra information and leaves it untouched.